# calling args from out side the main method

Tags: java, corba

I am developing a client server application where i can invoke server from the remote client and the some string is returned from the client. I am using `CORBA`. I have a user interface developed by using `Java Swing` on `Netbeans`. I need to invoke the server when a button is clicked on the client interface. For that I have to put following code segment inside `jButton`action listener.

```
private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         


        try{
        // create and initialize the ORB
        ORB orb = ORB.init(args, null);

        // get the root naming context
        org.omg.CORBA.Object objRef = 
            orb.resolve_initial_references("NameService");
        // Use NamingContextExt instead of NamingContext. This is 
        // part of the Interoperable naming Service.  
        NamingContextExt ncRef = NamingContextExtHelper.narrow(objRef);

        // resolve the Object Reference in Naming
        String name = "Hello";
        bsImpl = BubbleSortHelper.narrow(ncRef.resolve_str(name));

        //System.out.println("Obtained a handle on server object: " + helloImpl);
        String z = bsImpl.sort(inputFlArray);
        System.out.println(z);
        bsImpl.shutdown();

        } catch (Exception e) {
          System.out.println("ERROR : " + e) ;
          e.printStackTrace(System.out);
          }

    }
```

Once I compile it, I get the error saying args cannot be identified. I just copied `ORB orb = ORB.init(args, null);`  code segment from a place where it was inside the main method. I know that error comes up because of I used args outside the main method. 
I need to know that how can I initialize `ORB` object here outside the main method?

Comment: `args` is essentially just a String array. You can make a field for it in the class if you want and store it as `this.args = args;`.

Answer (score 1):

`String[] args` are passed to your `main()` method. I would recommend you initialize your ORB there, and pass the instance to your `JButton`'s constructor with something like -

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
  try{
    // create and initialize the ORB
    ORB orb = ORB.init(args, null);
    // ....
    JButton myButton = new MyButton(orb);
    // ....
  } catch (Exception e) {
    System.out.println("ERROR : " + e) ;
    e.printStackTrace(System.out);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually, if you want a new instance of ORB in every client's action. You could do it as below:

```
ORB orb = org.omg.CORBA.ORB.init(new String[0], null);
```

**public static ORB init(String[] args, Properties props)**
Creates a new ORB instance for a standalone application. This method may be called from applications only and returns a new fully functional ORB object each time it is called.
**Parameters:**
**args** - command-line arguments for the application's main method; may be null
**props** - application-specific properties; may be null

Here, args could be null, however, if you use null dirctly, it will be ambiguous with another method `org.omg.CORBA.ORB.init(Applet app, Properties props)`
Therefore, you could use emyty String arrays instead.

Normally, the args is not used, if you want to use it, you could pass it to your "jButtonaction listener" class.