# CORBA Error : ORB initialization in a method

Tags: java, corba

I am calling a method at the server side from the client side. I have three servers and they need to communicate using UDP so in the method i need to initialize the orb again to start the thread process.But am pretty sure this is because of a problem in ORB initialization

My method at the server side:

```
public String getNonReturners(String adminUsername, String adminPassword,
            String educationalInstitution, int numDays) {

        String _result = null;
        String _initiatedServerResult = null;
        final ArrayList<String> result = new ArrayList<String>();

        try {
            ORB orb = ORB.init();
            POA rootPOA = POAHelper.narrow(orb.resolve_initial_references("RootPOA"));
            BufferedReader brConcordia = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(
                    "concordia.txt"));
            String concordia = brConcordia.readLine();
            brConcordia.close();

            BufferedReader brMcgill = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(
                    "mcgill.txt"));
            String mcgill = brMcgill.readLine();
            brMcgill.close();

            BufferedReader brDawson = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(
                    "dawson.txt"));
            String dawson = brDawson.readLine();
            brDawson.close();
            org.omg.CORBA.Object concordiaObject = orb.string_to_object(concordia);
            org.omg.CORBA.Object mcgillObject = orb.string_to_object(mcgill);
            org.omg.CORBA.Object dawsonObject = orb.string_to_object(dawson);
            final DRMSInterface _concordiaServer = DRMSInterfaceHelper
                    .narrow(concordiaObject);
            final DRMSInterface _mcgillServer = DRMSInterfaceHelper
                    .narrow(mcgillObject);
            final DRMSInterface _dawsonServer = DRMSInterfaceHelper
                    .narrow(dawsonObject);

            if (educationalInstitution.toLowerCase().equals("concordia")) {
                final Thread t1 = new Thread() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        result.add(_mcgillServer
                                .responseData(_mcgillPortNumber));
                    }
                };
                t1.setDaemon(true);
                t1.start();
                final Thread t2 = new Thread() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        result.add(_dawsonServer
                                .responseData(_dawsonPortNumber));
                    }
                };
                t2.setDaemon(true);
                t2.start();

                System.out.println("Attemping to connect to " + IPAddress
                        + ") via UDP port" + _mcgillPortNumber);
                result.add("Attemping to connect to " + IPAddress
                        + ") via UDP port" + _mcgillPortNumber);
                result.add("/n");
                System.out.println("Attemping to connect to " + IPAddress
                        + ") via UDP port" + _dawsonPortNumber);
                result.add("Attemping to connect to " + IPAddress
                        + ") via UDP port" + _dawsonPortNumber);
                result.add("/n");
                final String _concordiaRequestMessage = educationalInstitution
                        + numDays;
                System.out.println("Sending data  "
                        + _concordiaRequestMessage.length()
                        + " bytes to server.");
                result.add("Sending data  " + _concordiaRequestMessage.length()
                        + " bytes to server.");
                result.add(_concordiaServer.requestData(_mcgillPortNumber,
                        _concordiaRequestMessage));
                result.add(_concordiaServer.requestData(_dawsonPortNumber,
                        _concordiaRequestMessage));
                _initiatedServerResult = _concordiaServer.getNonReturnersData(
                        educationalInstitution, numDays);
                if (_initiatedServerResult != null) {
                    result.add(_initiatedServerResult);
                }
                else {
                    result.add("No Defaulters in Concordia");
                }
            }
            else if (educationalInstitution.toLowerCase().equals("mcgill")) {
                final Thread t1 = new Thread() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        result.add(_concordiaServer
                                .responseData(_concordiaPortNumber));
                    }
                };
                t1.setDaemon(true);
                t1.start();
                final Thread t2 = new Thread() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        result.add(_dawsonServer
                                .responseData(_dawsonPortNumber));
                    }
                };
                t2.setDaemon(true);
                t2.start();

                System.out.println("Attemping to connect to " + IPAddress
                        + ") via UDP port" + _concordiaPortNumber);
                result.add("Attemping to connect to " + IPAddress
                        + ") via UDP port" + _concordiaPortNumber);
                System.out.println("Attemping to connect to " + IPAddress
                        + ") via UDP port" + _dawsonPortNumber);
                result.add("Attemping to connect to " + IPAddress
                        + ") via UDP port" + _dawsonPortNumber);
                final String _mcgillRequestMessage = educationalInstitution
                        + numDays;
                System.out.println("Sending data  "
                        + _mcgillRequestMessage.length() + " bytes to server.");
                result.add("Sending data  " + _mcgillRequestMessage.length()
                        + " bytes to server.");
                result.add(_mcgillServer.requestData(_concordiaPortNumber,
                        _mcgillRequestMessage));
                result.add(_mcgillServer.requestData(_dawsonPortNumber,
                        _mcgillRequestMessage));
                _initiatedServerResult = _mcgillServer.getNonReturnersData(
                        educationalInstitution, numDays);
                if (_initiatedServerResult != null) {
                    result.add(_initiatedServerResult);
                }
                else {
                    result.add("No Defaulters in Mcgill");
                }

            }
            else if (educationalInstitution.toLowerCase().equals("dawson")) {
                final Thread t1 = new Thread() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        result.add(_concordiaServer
                                .responseData(_concordiaPortNumber));
                    }
                };
                t1.setDaemon(true);
                t1.start();
                final Thread t2 = new Thread() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        result.add(_mcgillServer
                                .responseData(_mcgillPortNumber));
                    }
                };
                t2.setDaemon(true);
                t2.start();

                System.out.println("Attemping to connect to " + IPAddress
                        + ") via UDP port" + _concordiaPortNumber);
                result.add("Attemping to connect to " + IPAddress
                        + ") via UDP port" + _concordiaPortNumber);
                System.out.println("Attemping to connect to " + IPAddress
                        + ") via UDP port" + _mcgillPortNumber);
                result.add("Attemping to connect to " + IPAddress
                        + ") via UDP port" + _mcgillPortNumber);

                final String _dawsonRequestMessage = educationalInstitution
                        + numDays;
                System.out.println("Sending data  "
                        + _dawsonRequestMessage.length() + " bytes to server.");
                result.add("Sending data  " + _dawsonRequestMessage.length()
                        + " bytes to server.");
                result.add(_dawsonServer.requestData(_concordiaPortNumber,
                        _dawsonRequestMessage));
                result.add(_dawsonServer.requestData(_mcgillPortNumber,
                        _dawsonRequestMessage));
                result.add(_concordiaServer.getNonReturnersData(
                        educationalInstitution, numDays));
                _initiatedServerResult = _dawsonServer.getNonReturnersData(
                        educationalInstitution, numDays);
                if (_initiatedServerResult != null) {
                    result.add(_initiatedServerResult);
                }
                else {
                    result.add("No Defaulters in Dawson");
                }
            }
        }
        catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        catch (InvalidName e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return _result = result.toString();
    }
```

I tried the last answer in this question but it doesn't help.
[calling args from out side the main method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25245355/calling-args-from-out-side-the-main-method)

Error:

```
org.omg.CORBA.NO_IMPLEMENT: ----------BEGIN server-side stack trace----------
org.omg.CORBA.NO_IMPLEMENT:   vmcid: SUN  minor code: 201  completed: No
    at com.sun.corba.se.impl.logging.ORBUtilSystemException.genericNoImpl(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.corba.se.impl.logging.ORBUtilSystemException.genericNoImpl(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.corba.se.impl.orb.ORBSingleton.resolve_initial_references(Unknown Source)
    at DistributedReservationManagementSystem.DRMSInterfaceImpl.getNonReturners(DRMSInterfaceImpl.java:448)
    at DistributedReservationManagementSystem.DRMSInterfacePOA._invoke_getNonReturners(DRMSInterfacePOA.java:224)
    at DistributedReservationManagementSystem.DRMSInterfacePOA.access$9(DRMSInterfacePOA.java:215)
    at DistributedReservationManagementSystem.DRMSInterfacePOA$Operation_getNonReturners.invoke(DRMSInterfacePOA.java:385)
    at DistributedReservationManagementSystem.DRMSInterfacePOA._invoke(DRMSInterfacePOA.java:73)
    at com.sun.corba.se.impl.protocol.CorbaServerRequestDispatcherImpl.dispatchToServant(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.corba.se.impl.protocol.CorbaServerRequestDispatcherImpl.dispatch(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.corba.se.impl.protocol.CorbaMessageMediatorImpl.handleRequestRequest(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.corba.se.impl.protocol.CorbaMessageMediatorImpl.handleRequest(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.corba.se.impl.protocol.CorbaMessageMediatorImpl.handleInput(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.corba.se.impl.protocol.giopmsgheaders.RequestMessage_1_2.callback(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.corba.se.impl.protocol.CorbaMessageMediatorImpl.handleRequest(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.corba.se.impl.transport.SocketOrChannelConnectionImpl.dispatch(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.corba.se.impl.transport.SocketOrChannelConnectionImpl.doWork(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.corba.se.impl.orbutil.threadpool.ThreadPoolImpl$WorkerThread.performWork(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.corba.se.impl.orbutil.threadpool.ThreadPoolImpl$WorkerThread.run(Unknown Source)

----------END server-side stack trace----------  vmcid: SUN  minor code: 201  completed: No
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.corba.se.impl.protocol.giopmsgheaders.MessageBase.getSystemException(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.corba.se.impl.protocol.giopmsgheaders.ReplyMessage_1_2.getSystemException(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.corba.se.impl.protocol.CorbaMessageMediatorImpl.getSystemExceptionReply(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.corba.se.impl.protocol.CorbaClientRequestDispatcherImpl.processResponse(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.corba.se.impl.protocol.CorbaClientRequestDispatcherImpl.marshalingComplete(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.corba.se.impl.protocol.CorbaClientDelegateImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.omg.CORBA.portable.ObjectImpl._invoke(Unknown Source)
    at DistributedReservationManagementSystem._DRMSInterfaceStub.getNonReturners(_DRMSInterfaceStub.java:502)
    at DistributedReservationManagementSystem.DRMSInterfaceClient.main(DRMSInterfaceClient.java:362)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I resolved it like this reading it from a property file:

```
try {
            Properties prop = new Properties();
            String[] orbarg = new String[2];

            try {
                // load a properties file
                prop.load(new FileInputStream("config.properties"));
                // get the property value and print it out  
                orbarg[0] = "-ORBInitRef"; // <---- NEEDED
                orbarg[1] = prop.getProperty("ORBInitRef");

            } catch (IOException ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }

            ORB orb = ORB.init(orbarg,null);
```

It works even when we pass it a blank string array as argument